# How do I disconnect from my database gracefully in a callback / promise - based environment?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to know how to disconnect from my MySQL database after lots of individual callbacks have finished. I have a node.js cron script running on AWS EC2 which accesses s3 buckets and MySQL databases on AWS RDS. The cron script looks something like this:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2"),
  AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
  s3 = new AWS.S3(),
  connection = mysql.connect({...});

connection.connect();

connection.query(`SELECT ... LIMIT 100`, (error, results) => {
   if (error) throw new Error(error);
   for (let idx in results) {
      const row = results[idx],
            Key = `my/key/${row.id}`;

      s3.getObject({Bucket, Key}, (error, object) => {
          // do more things, with more callbacks
      });
   }
});

setTimeout(() => connection.end(), 10000);  // disconnect database in 10 seconds
```

The script doesn't exit until I disconnect from the database using `connection.end()`. I can't disconnect as normal e.g. after the `for` loop, because the various callbacks are still running. I need to know when they're all finished. Currently I just disconnect after 10 seconds because everything should have completed by then. If I don't do that then I end up with lots of never-ending processes running.

Do I need to set flags & counts of each thing, and then use `setInterval` or something until they're all finished and it's safe to disconnect? OK to do but is that the right approach when using callbacks, promises & thens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with counters or flags as you said, or with Promise.all:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2"),
  AWS = require("aws-sdk"),
  s3 = new AWS.S3(),
  connection = mysql.connect({...});

function doQuery(){
  connection.connect();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    connection.query(`SELECT ... LIMIT 100`, (error, results) => {
      if (error) { return reject(new Error(error)); }
      resolve(results)
   });
  })
}

doQuery()
  .then(results => {
    const jobs = results.map(row => {
      const Key = `my/key/${row.id}`;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject({Bucket, Key}, (error, object) => {
          // do more things, with more callbacks
          resolve('ok')
        });
      })

    })

    return Promise.all(jobs)
  })
  .finally(()=>{
    connection.end()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post as well that `Promise.all()` is definitely a great way to go, however it's not the only approach.

In this day & age, where the cost of connecting to & disconnecting from your database can be very cheap, I find it simpler to just connect on every query and disconnect after:

```js
const dbOneQuery = (sql, bindVars, callback) => {
  const dbConnection = getConnection(); // mysql2.createConnection etc
  dbConnection.query(sql, bindVars, (error, result) => {
    dbConnection.end();
    if (callback) callback(error, result);
  });
};
```

and that way there aren't any connections held open to be closed.

If in future I move to persistent connections again, I can just change what `getConnection()` does and use something that overrides `.end()` etc..

For me this approach has been simpler overall compared to managing a single shared connection to the database, with no real downsides.